# Why would a Content & Structure Report not show items from subsites?

Tags: publishing-site, content-and-structure, reports

Normally the Content and Structure reports will show items in the current site and any of it's subsites.

I have a MOSS 2007 environment where the Site Owner is not seeing all items pending approval when they access the "Pending Approvals" report.

We can see pending items in this report if they select one of the lower level nodes in the tree structure, just not from the top node.

I've checked the CAML for the Pending Approval report and it has not been altered in any way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Ivan, we are experiencing the same issue. Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 1):

Having done some investigation on this, I think you will find this is down to the fact that by default they can only query 1000 lists. If you go into the report definition you can override this by entering "" into the "CAML List Type" field. The '0' here means no limit. Doing this however could cause problems in your environment as the reports place quite a load on the server.

An alternative approach might be to filter the reports by ServerTemplate. We wantd to only view items from the Pages library. We achieved this by putting "" in the "CAML List Type" field.

Hope this helps.